# When tomcat server is installed on my j2ee eclipse, is there any extra componenets need to configure EJB'S?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ejb

I installed tomcat 8.0 on my eclipse j2ee(web developers), is there any need to download extra components from internet for configuring EJB'S?

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is community based on concept of helping each other.You should not expect others to reply you according to your deadlines.Probably you first need to see [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Now about your question :

Tomact is a Servlet container.You need an application server(e.g. weblogic/glassfish) to deploy your EJBs.

Anyways you can have a look over [TomEE](http://openejb.apache.org/apache-tomee.html).

It has got support for enterprise components(EJBs)

Comment: Tomcat is a server not a container...

Comment: Its both ,a web server for serving HTTP requests and a container for deployment of web resources(JSP/Servlet).We normally refer Tomcat as Servlet container